# Create combobox in Excel through SAS

Tags: excel, combobox, sas

My question is the following, is there a way of generating an Excel combobox through SAS coding?? And if so, can someone illuminate me with some code?

I am trying to generate an Excel file about election polls.

The combobox will be filled with political parties, such as Party A, Party B and Party C.

And for every user, he/she will have to pick one.

But I want to generate the Excel through SAS.

The output would be something like this:

[image: Example Output]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you say more about what you're trying to do, and why?  Could be easier to just created the combo box in Excel, and then have SAS write data used to populate it.

Comment: The exact item I would like it to be is the Data Validation like dropdown list.

Comment: From this link, tagsets.excelxp can't do it.  https://communities.sas.com/message/168384 I suppose it's possible 9.4 ODS EXCEL destination could do it, but I'd be surprised.  Might be better off using SAS to write your citizen list etc to one sheet, and metadata for your party choice options to another sheet, then using VBA (or even DDE) to create the combo box.

Comment: You can probably do it through DDE, but that's likely the only way that's easy.  Since you could theoretically write out an excel file as a text file, you _could_ do it in some fashion, but that's undoubtedly beyond the scope of what you're trying here.  Are you familiar with DDE?